# Angular.js : CORS HttpInterceptor that transforms $http.get into $http.jsonp request transparently

Tags: json, angularjs, cross-domain, jsonp, cors

I've been looking into if it's possible to create a web based version of my [Chrome Plugin](http://schizoduckie.github.io/DuckieTV)
now that it's relying completely on Trakt.TV's JSON API.

According to angular's documentation, it's possible to intercept HTTP requests at several levels, one is the HTTP Backend itself (mainly used for testing though) and the other is HTTPInterceptor.get

The basic idea is to wrap calls to Trakt.TV's JSONP api through http://json2jsonp.com/ and have them returned transparently to get around cross site scripting restrictions. This would not only be very useful for my own project, but for a lot of other people daeling with the same issues too (therefore i'll release the module after it's done, but I want to do it properly)

**The basics should be simple**:

- Hook the $http.get request at the right level
- Overwrite the original request made
- Cancel an optional other request already set up
- Hook it through $http.jsonp(http://json2jsonp.com/)
- Return the original promise's success/fail when done

**Questions**:

- Has anyone built anything like this yet? (Github searches revealed nothing)
- Would you suggest using the HTTPBackend or the HTTPInterceptor?

Answer (score 0):

why can't you just use the jsonp helper function?
httpBakend is a mockup service to fake a backend server is not used on live code. http interceptors would do what you want you just need to attach the callback function name to your request if the url contains what ever name you want to filter and then in the response interceptor you have to pass response to the callback function so the json to be evaluated. be aware that interceptors will inspect every request makde by angular which is not very eficien, unless you are only doing calls to the tv service. 
like i said before a better approach is to use $http.jsonp function

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp

a word about interceptors they need to be defined as services and then be passed to HttpProvider during your apps configuration.

Comment: I know about $http.jsonp. That is what i'll be using to proxy the requests through. My point is that I want to keep the original request intact, wether it's $http.xml, jsonp, get or whatever

Comment: maybe i miss understood you, you don't want to keep the "request" intact but the code that generates the request is that right?